# Change url path inside css after build prod on Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm hosting my application on subdomain ex: https://www.example.com/subdomain/app/ and inside the scss files I have some fonts

```
    font-family: 'Gibson'
    src: url('/static/fonts/gibson/regular/gibson-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/static/fonts/gibson/regular/gibson-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight: 400
    font-style: normal
```

It works on my development env localhost:8000/ but on my production env (ex: https://www.example.com/subdomain/app/) it couldn't load the fonts because of folder path it tries to search on https://www.example.com/static/etc...

The html index style is

```
<link href="/access/app/inside/static/css/app.css" rel="preload" as="style">
```

And my **app.css** still pointing to

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face{
font-family:Gibson;
src:url(/static/fonts/gibson/bold/gibson-bold-webfont.woff2)format("woff2")
```

I don't know if this is possible or if exist a way to manage this on Vuejs. Is it a way to change this css path on build? I can't find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using vue-cli to generate the project? Are you including the sass file in your SFC or as a global import?

Comment: If using Vue CLI, have you set the `publicPath` option in `vue.config.js`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using yarn prod. I tried to use publicPath, it didn't work. The path on development is working localhost:8000/static/, but my production env have different path so it is not finding the correct path, it should work on https://www.example.com/subdomain/app/static/fonts/ but it tries https://www.example.com/static/fonts/ because the path is inside the scss and goes to the app.css without updating. I'm not finding a way to correct this path automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a setup with sass and webpack to change the path based on environment variables with a plugin or through some custom function. But I think the easiest way is to use the default functionality, like putting the fonts in the assets folder, and then when you reference them from there, that gets resolved automatically by the parser.

#### update 1

in a new vue-cli (v3.4.1) generated app I added a font file to he `assets` folder. Then added this scss (should be similar for sass) to `App.vue` - the link is relative to the app

```css
<style lang="scss">
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('./assets/Gibson-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
#app {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
}
```

It works whether I run the application using the dev server, or serve the built dist folder (as root or as nested)

#### update 2

if `publicPath` is not working it's most likely because you are using absolute paths in your css. **Remove the leading `/` character from your paths**

`src:url(/static/fonts/gibson/bold/gibson.....` will break

use 
`src:url(@/src/static/fonts/gibson/bold/gibson...`  or whatever relative path you need

and set your `publicPath` to `/subdomain/app`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, how can I do this? Is it possible to update paths on css after run build? Or before? On my html is correct path, the page works well, it only can't find the font founder because of the path inside css. thanks again.

Comment: how do you include your `app.css`?

Comment: the project is using typescript, it is imported in Main.ts  - import "@/sass/app.sass"; I think is here. And I have vue.config.js too. Don't know if it helps.

Comment: did you remove the leading `/` from your paths?

Comment: yes, I got an error on yarn build-prod -  error  in ./src/sass/app.sass it didn't find the path. The font is not in google fonts so I have to use this path to the font files, the project is already in production, but the font is wrong. It has to be a way to change this on production. Thanks for your help.